# doxygen link to objective-c method in category

Tags: objective-c, documentation, doxygen, objective-c-category

I found it is hard to link method in category with doxygen.

For example with the following code:

```
@interface A
-(void)method;
@end

@interface A(Category)
-(void)methodInCategory
@end
```

I found that doxygen works like so:

```
@ref A(Category)   => Success to link: A(Category)
@link A::method    => Success to link: A -method
```

but with the following code:

```
@link A(Category)::methodInCategory  => Fail to link
```

I always got the error:

```
warning: unable to resolve link to `A(Category)::methodInCategory' for \link command
```

I am using doxygen 1.8.1.2

How can I make a link to method in category, or is it a bug of doxygen?

Comment: Offtopic, but if in case you don't know [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) you should take a look.

Comment: In fact, I found appledoc just some hours ago, and regreted about using doxygen. But at first trial, I found appledoc doesn't build doxygen commands very well. So I am trying easy way first. I think I will move to appledoc if I fails here. Thank you for advise!

Comment: I tried appledoc, but I found it doesn't support C function yet.

Comment: @youknowone I use your lib UI7Kit. How I can make that this will make customize all without UINavigationController. Or Another Question how I can add rule what ViewController I don't want to Customize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a really old post, but just in case someone was having this problem like I was, this actually seems to work now.  I am using doxygen 1.8.9.1  using:

```
@ref A(Category)::methodInCategory
```

worked for me, but the link produced was a bit odd as it left out the class name and produced:  '::methodInCategory'